# meaning of "betraying no evidence of nerves"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The man’s eyes stayed hidden under the shadow of the hood, but his jaw
> was set and his hands, particularly the one holding the knife, were
> rock-steady, **betraying no evidence of nerves.**

What does this betraying no evidence of nerves means? does it mean that he's nervous but his firm grip of the knife showing it?

Comment: [The fact that his hands were steady] meant that there was no sign that he might be nervous.

Comment: We don't *know* if he's nervous or not. All we know is that if he *is* nervous, he's doing a good job of covering it up (we can't see any evidence of him being nervous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the key word giving you trouble is the verb "betray". It is important to note its meaning here, according to Lexico:

> unintentionally reveal; be evidence of.
> "she drew a deep breath that betrayed her indignation"

Another thing to pay attention to is when "nerve" is used as a plural noun, it means "nervousness". Again from Lexico:

> nervousness or anxiety.
> "his first-night nerves soon disappeared"

Therefore, here "betraying no evidence of nerves" means "showing no evidence of his nervousness."